# Cannot call EntityModel from c# code-file

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-model

I created an EntityModel in Visual Studio 2010 to use with Linq. What I see in my Model Browser are:

```
>AcrrualEntityModel.edmx
>>SteeringWheelModel
>>>Entity Types
>>>>TblFTEReportNew
>>>>>Field1
>>>>>etc..
```

In my Default.aspx.cs file I should be able to call SteeringWheelModel. This object is generated with the Entity Data Model Wizard. I can see the tables and fields in the model. So, the connection to the database works.

However, in my Default.aspx.cs file I should be able to create a new instance of SteeringWheelModel, so I can use Linq to use tables and fields.

Intellisense does not pick it up. The compiler does not recognize SteeringWheelModel.

What am I missing here? Some "using", some reference?

Thanks in advance!

Roy

Comment: Probably some `using`, yes.

Comment: Make sure that your aspx page and edmx both are on same project. if they are not than add reference of the edmx's project to the main project.

Comment: They are in the same Solution. So my guess is that a reference is not necessary. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: aspx.cs and the edmx should be inside same name space.

Comment: Ok, so the AcrrualEntityModel.Designer.cs has the same namespace as Default.asmx.cs for sure. However, the edmx file uses <Schema Namespace="SteeringWheelModel"...  That definitely is different than the namespce in Default.aspx.cs. So, I should change that namespace to the namespace as in Default.aspx.cs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the namespace of EntityModel class by adding a using statement to your code behind.  Ex:

```
using app.data.models
```

Alternatively you *could* make sure they are in the same namespace, but I do not recommend that.  Also, if these files are in differenet projects make sure your UI project has a reference to the EntityModel project.

Edit:  To try to show you what I mean.

[image: Sample Project]

Here is a section of one of my projects.  Each folder here has a different namespace.

```
data.abstract
data.concrete
data.entities
```

If I want to reference a class in another UI project i first need to add a reference to the data assembly to the UI project and then inside the UI project I need to import the namespace ex:

```
using data.abstract;
using data.entities;
```

Comment: When I change the namespace in the edmx-file to the one as in Default.aspx.cs, it doesn't recognize the namespace in the edmx-file.  When I try to set "using" in my Default.aspx.cs file, it doesn't pick up the Namespace as used in the edmx-file. So I set "using SteeringWheel;" in my Default.aspx.cs. The compiler doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Then you liking need to add an assembly reference to the project that includes that namespace.

Comment: Ok, so I right-click in "References", browse to obj/release/TempPE and add "AcrrualEntityModel.Designer.cs.dll". I can see the reference in Solution Explorer. Still, I can't use SteeringWheelModel. I guess I added the wrong reference?

Comment: Add Reference -> Projects -> select your EntityModel Project -> click OK.  You should then see your assembly under References in your UI project.

Comment: Thank you for trying to explain. Maybe I need a step-by-step tutorial to add an Entitymodel to an existing SQLServer database.

Comment: I can't find the EntityModel-project, because the EntiyModel is in the same Solution. There is nothing to choose from.

Comment: Is your default.aspx.cs inside a namespace?  If not, you will need to import the name of your project (default assigned namespace) in the code behind or include the code behind in the namespace.   Post your default.aspx.cs

Comment: Yes it is in a namespace:

Comment: You need to post your default.aspx.cs where the EntityModel is failing.

Comment: >using System;
>using System.Collections.Generic;
>using System.Linq;
>using System.Web;
>using System.Web.UI;
>using System.Web.UI.WebControls;



>namespace Exam70315_Chachp11Les2
>{
>   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
>    {
>        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>        {
>           
>            if (!IsPostBack)
>            {
>                SteeringWheelModel.SteeringWheelEntities sw = new SteeringWheelModel.SteeringWheelEntities();
>               
>          }
>        }
>    }
>}

Comment: You should be able to directly reference SteeringWheelEntities.

Comment: It doen't recognize "SteeringWheelModel". Sorry for the code. The editor concatenates my lines

Comment: That's correct! It does reference it directly. Now a green warning applies with :"No Metadata Documentation Available". However, it is not an error.

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SteeringWheelEntities sw = new SteeringWheelEntities();

                var personQuery = from p in sw.tblPerson
                                  orderby p.LastName
                                  select p;

                
            }

Comment: Now I deleted the reference to the dll and all works! No warnings, I have a query running. Thank you all!